# Using OneHotEncoder removes labels from dataframe

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding, dummy-variable

Using `OneHotEncoder` on the column containing categorical variable removes labels from the entire dataframe. Any solution to this? I do not want to lose labels of my dataframe.

```
labelencoder_1 = LabelEncoder()
df1['MSZoning'] = labelencoder_1.fit_transform(df1['MSZoning'])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [2])
df1 = onehotencoder.fit_transform(df1).toarray()
```

Comment: What do you mean removes labels from the entire dataframe, does it affect other columns aswell?

Comment: i mean it removes the column names and replaces them by numbers

Comment: @CeliusStingher